# Is this safe for login throught ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, json, authentication

Is it safe when Iam using ajax for login like that? Iam not sure if input value in jquery part are safe enought for that. Should I use some libraries for md5, sha1 in jquery?

Iam talking about this part:

```
data: { mail: $('.login_form .mail').val(), pass: $('.login_form .pass').val() }
```

Full:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./ajax/identifyLogin.php",
            data: { mail: $('.login_form .mail').val(), pass: $('.login_form .pass').val() },
            dataType:'JSON', //or HTML, JSON, etc.
            success: function(response){
                if (response.status == "fail") {
                  e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
});
```

and in identifyLogin.php I have this code

```
$mail = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["mail"]));
        $password = sha1(md5($_POST["pass"]));
        if($mail == "" || $password == ""){
            echo json_encode(array("status"=>"fail"));
        }else{
            $data = mysql_query("select * from users where mail='$mail' and password='$password'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($data) == 0){
                echo json_encode(array("status"=>"fail"));
            } else {
                while($radek = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
                    echo json_encode(array("status"=>"success")); 
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: AJAX is a regular http request. There is nothing special in ajax. Seriously - **NOTHING**. PS: `sha1(md5())` -- ohhhhhhhh

Comment: As long as it's HTTP, it's not safe. If you calculate a checksum and send it instead of the password, the only thing you're achieving is not send the password through an unsecure protocol. However if someone steals the checksum, he can log in using that with no problem. Security wise - no gain.

Comment: @mamdouh alramadan: delete your comment please. You have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan The link you posted is about sql injections, what has to do with ajax?

Comment: @zerkms, :)) `sha1(md5())` reminds me of `des(des(des()))`

Comment: @mamdouh alramadan: it **is** enough. As I already mentioned - you have serious lack of knowledge about it.

Comment: @zerkms Sql injections are a responsibility of the server not of the client, the javascript. You can never trust the client.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan, you clearly don't understand how SQL Injection works. It's easy once you know SQL. As long as the values are in quotes, and the quotes in the values are escaped, there is NO WAY to perform an SQL injection.

Comment: @ManolisAgkopian, he is not doing SQL injection protection on the client side.

Comment: @Manolis Agkopian: okay. Why are you telling it to me though?

Comment: @mamdouh alramadan: please read about how `mysql_real_escape_string` works.

Comment: So in summary - everything is fine and Iam unaviable to be hacked?

Comment: @Jessie: have you read my first comment?

Comment: @AlexanderMP He said “the question is saying is it safe, I think safety includes sql injection too. I pointed out that it is not safe, as using mysql_real_scape_string is not enough.” The only thing I understand from what he said is “You should also escape your string with javascript before making the ajax request”

Comment: @zerkms yes I did but Iam not sure if it means that iam ok :D

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan, do you see a `SET NAMES gbk` anywhere?
@ManolisAgkopian, why isn't that enough?

Comment: Jessie, there is nothing special about AJAX, but you still have to take all the precautions you would with any other http authentication request. It is a complex subject with a lot of subtle things that can be done to attack you.

Comment: @mamdouh alramadan: please read "The Ugly" part of the answer you've given a link to. You will see that `mysql_real_escape_string` is not broken. I realize First class professionals don't read much, but please try your best and read ircmaxell's answer entirely. Thank you.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan Ok I'm sorry then I didn't understand what you mean. The point is the question is about if ajax is secure for sending sensitive data or not. It does not asking about how to prevent sql injections.

Comment: @Jerry so It's easier not to use ajax for a login.

Comment: Nothing is ever 100% safe. However, it depends on what you are trying to allow, or not. Currently, safest is 'HTTPS' but costs money and programming. For the rest of us, reasonable precautions are the way to go. If someone is 'out to get you' then it is impossible to prevent. As in 'real life' there is nothing you can do about it. But it is very unlikely.

Comment: @Jessie - ajax has nothing to do with securing data transmission, nor encrypting data in the client side. if you do care about sensitive data transmission, you need to use a secure protocol, (SSL) in your case

Comment: @Jessie, in short, for the server using ajax or not is the exact same thing. Either using ajax or not the server will get an http request, so just sanitize and validate your input the exact same way you do when you don't use ajax. Using ajax does not make your application more or less secure.

Comment: @ManolisAgkopian oh well, thats what I wanted to hear. Now I should change things in identifyLogin.php as I read...

Comment: Instead of going into details about obscure scenarios, is it not a better suggestion to use UTF-8 everywhere? (Languages still miss excellent support for using multiple codepages/encodings; and in the very rare case where someone needs to use a different codepage for optimalization some more follow-up reading is called for anyways.) It's harder to make mistakes if you use a single charset/encoding everywhere, and UTF-8 is the most common default among correct components.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead, `mysql_*` is [depreciated](http://php.net/function.mysql-connect)

Using ajax to login in itself is not a problem but the ony way to be certain that user credentials are not captured is by using `HTTPS` with a signed `SSL` certificate

Comment: "and vulnerable to some exploits." --- any references?

Comment: Might take me a while to find but I'll look, I read it somewhere

Comment: Just using mysqli_ or PDO does not make your application more secure by itself, you need to also use prepared statements. As for the "mysql_* is depreciated" I agree with that, it should be never used in new code as it might get removed from future versions of php.

Comment: @zerkms couldn't find any :)

Comment: @ManolisAgkopian agreed about prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

By itself AJAX is not more/less secure than a standard HTML form postback; so you should definitely use HTTPS. But your solution has many problems there, just to name a few:

- only store the passwords hashed with a salt
- use better hashes than sha1, if you can
- do not transmit passwords, hash them on the client using a salt provided (and checked against the current session) by the server
- use a server-side checking that is time-constant
- use PDO or mysqli

The question suggests you are not strong on security yet. I advise you use a sophisticated framework (like Symfony2), because they are exactly about trying to prevent such security leaks.

Comment: What can be better for me than sha1(md5())?

Comment: First, there is no point in calculating the SHA-1 of an MD5; add CPU cycles does not add any security. AFAIK SHA-1 has known weaknesses while SHA-256 does not (not checked that in a while, might be in error). I would use the strongest available hashing algorithm. If (by the expected server load) it takes 1-2 seconds, the better. One login is something the user can wait for, but protecting access and the password itself should be top priority. I suppose, your best bet for the far future is to use the strongest method you can.